# Web deploy .NET client-side assemblies in Firefox?

Tags: .net, firefox, client-side, gecko

I have a **very large** client application written over the course of several years in .NET (actually a collection of assemblies) that we're trying to make web-deployable. This was a moderate task in Internet Explorer that required wrapping the libraries in a COM and interacting with it through Javascript. This works fine.

The next challenge is to get it working in Firefox and potentially other Gecko-based browsers (Windows only though.) I've been looking at the [Gecko plug-in functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins) but near as I can tell it doesn't support .NET code.

Does anyone know if/how I can get this to work with .NET assemblies? Or alternatively, is there any other way to get .NET client code running within Firefox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "web deployable". Do you mean, "runs in the browser and interacts with JavaScript?"

Comment: Or alternatively, is there any other way to get .NET client code running within Firefox? - No, you cannot do this as the virus potential would be insane!

Comment: In IE, the assemblies, ActiveX + other .NET DLLs, are packaged up in a CAB installed on the client, registered with RegAsm, and can be loaded up in the Javascript. I'm trying to figure out some kind of similar architecture for FF.

Comment: @NickGotch "Plugin". There might be a proxy/harness, but FF does not - and will not - support ActiveX (it punts on the historical MSXML variant) without a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: The ActiveX wrapper was done so it would run in IE, it's not necessary for this effort. These are also not home PCs, they're business machines running across a company that only supports FF, ie: this is a corporate setting where a plugin could be deployed across the board.

Comment: Isn't that was Adobe Flex was for?

Comment: Can I host a .NET project in Flex? The major obstacle is that the codebase for this client piece is huge so rewriting it isn't an option. Basically I'm just looking for a way to host it in FF. Using an ActiveX wrapper worked beautifully in IE; I'll take anything that would do the same in FF.

Comment: Thanks @pst I found this and am looking into it http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/plugin.htm

Comment: @NickGotch Self-answer if you find a solution.